# Vba Object doesn't get added to collection

Tags: vba, class, collections

I have a class with a collection 'verrichtinglijst' as member. I try to add an object 'verr' to it but it doesn't get added and it gives no error message. Does anybody see why it doesn't get added? It does get to the line of 'verrichtinglijst.Add verr' but it just passes without being added. Thanks in advance. This is my code (inside a class):

```
Public volgnrAfschrift As String
Public rekeningnummer As String
Public verrichtinglijst As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set verrichtinglijst = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub CreateRekeningUitreksel(rekuittrektxt As String)
Dim i, k, j As Long
Dim eerstetwee, line, txtToAdd, eerste As String
Dim verr As New verrichting

i = Len(rekuittrektxt)
i = i / 128

For j = 0 To i - 1
k = 128 * j
line = Mid(rekuittrektxt, k + 1, 128)
eerstetwee = Left(line, 2)
eerste = Left(line, 1)
If eerstetwee = "12" Then
rekeningnummer = Mid(line, 6, 31)
End If

If eerste = "2" Or eerste = "3" Then
    If eerstetwee = "21" Then
        If txtToAdd <> "" Then
        Call verr.CreateVerrichting(txtToAdd)
        verrichtinglijst.Add verr
        txtToAdd = ""
        End If
    End If
txtToAdd = txtToAdd & line
ElseIf eerste = "9" And txtToAdd <> "" Then
    Call verr.CreateVerrichting(txtToAdd)
    verrichtingenlijst.Add verr
End If

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: `verrichtinglijst.Add verr` and  `verrichtingenlijst.Add verr` is not the same.

Comment: The line `Dim i, k, j As Long` and `Dim eerstetwee, line, txtToAdd, eerste As String` will also not work as you might think becausoe of a [common error](https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/a-common-mistake-when-declaring-variables-in-vba/) you made. Look also at [Option Explicit](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dim/#Option_Explicit)

Comment: yes, indeed, I looked at verrichtingenlijst but it added to verrichtinglijst! Thanks

Comment: Thanks also for the remark on the dim!